# Java MySQL JDBC not accepting remote address

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have some code that is just trying to connect to a remote mysql instance.  When I try to connect, it is trying to connect to the local box, not the address I provided.

```
public class JdbcTest {
  static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://remoteAddress:port/orderup";
  static final String USER = myuser;
  static final String PASS = mypass;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
       Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVRE);
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       String sql = "select * from dual);
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

It never gets pass the `DriverManager` statement.  I get an access denied with the address of the box i am logged into, not the remote address i put into the jdbc url.  What gives?

I am using Java 8, MySQL 5.6.20, and com.mysql:mysql-connector:5.1.6

Comment: what is that remoteAddress? It should be the IP address of your DB server.

Comment: it is the ip address of my remote server.

Comment: What exception you are getting? Can you please paste the stack trace

Comment: Could you connect the same DB with another tool? Not JDBC? Could be an issue with closed port or something like this

Comment: I am able to go to the remote server and log in command line using mysql without error.

Comment: mysqld is running and connected to 0.0.0.0:3306 when looking at netstat -tanp

Comment: Try to connect remotely , not from the remote server.

Comment: What is the server? does it have a firewall? can you connect to port 3306 with telnet?

Comment: Try to connect from the same computer that you are executing your java code (Using Mysql workbench for example)